# How to read GlobalResources in ASP.NET MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can't find a way to read resource values in a controller

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're referring to string resources stored in App_GlobalResources then you can add a

```
using Resources;
```

and access them via

```
Strings.<name of resource>
```

or use

```
Resources.Strings.<name of resource>
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your warm help! + Happy New Year! ;o)