# How to access global resources in a view using asp.net mvc 5 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a resource file in `App_GlobalResources` named `Translations.resx` and `Translations.fr.resx`.

How do I reference these from my view using razor?

When I try using this:

```
@MYAPP.Resources.Translations.menuDashboard Or
@Resources.Translations.menuDashboard
```

than got Compile time error:

> The type or namespace name 'Resources' does not exist in the namespace

Comment: Does your resx file have a Public access modifier (in the resx file when it is opened) and is it using the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator Custom Tool (in the properties window of the resx file) ?

Comment: See [Resource Files and ASP.NET MVC Projects](https://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx) - there is a big gotcha when using `App_GlobalResources` in MVC. Also see [How to read GlobalResources in ASP.NET MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406083/how-to-read-globalresources-in-asp-net-mvc-controller) - you are missing the imports in your view. (`@using Resources`).